# Ubuntu 20.04 startup script does not run at startup

Tags: scripts, autostart

I have a simple script that I set up in Startup Programs but it's never run at startup. I have to run the script manualy instead.

```
# cat ~/.config/autostart/bash.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/bin/bash -c sleep 5 && /home/jedrek/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[pl]=Keyboard keys swapper
Name=Name Xmodmap
Comment[pl]=Swap right Option with right Command
Comment=Swap right Option with right Command
```

Shell script

```
cat ~/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh      
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Super_R"
xmodmap -e "keycode 134 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

Why doesn't it run and how to fix it?

Comment: Hello. A good start to a fix is what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 20.04. I've updated the title of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c sleep 5 && /home/jedrek/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh
```

Two commands are not supported with desktop files. Instead change to

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'sleep 5 && /home/jedrek/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh'
```

so bash can interpret the `&&` (which it understands) and thus execute your script after the delay.

Comment: Thank you, that did it! :-)