# Shell script does not run at desktop startup

Tags: bash, startup-applications

I already potted a similar question here [Ubuntu 20.04 startup script does not run at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402453/ubuntu-20-04-startup-script-does-not-run-at-startup) but after upgrading to 21.10 it no longer works.
This is my startup script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/bin/bash -c '/home/jedrek/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh'
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Keys swapper
Name=Keyboard swap
Comment[en_US]=Swap right Option with right CMD
Comment=Swap right Option with right CMD
```

but it never gets run. I even tried prepending `sleep 3` before the actual script file it it doesn't work either.

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'sleep 3 && /home/jedrek/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh'
```

I dont understand why. When I execute the script manually from terminal it works fine.

```
./keyboard_keys_swapper.sh
```

Why doesn't it work at startup?

Comment: The command has changed. What happens if you try the command elaborated in your other question? How do you come to upgrade to 21.10, a release that will be EOL within a couple of weeks?

Comment: As I said, `Exec=/bin/bash -c 'sleep && /home/jedrek/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh'` does not work either.

Comment: Why you don't add `sleep 5` in body script before all commands?

Comment: Why should I sleep before any command?

Comment: no... just add once in the beginning of script
`#!/bin/bash
sleep 5`

Comment: But why should I?

Comment: Exec=/bin/bash -c 'sleep && /home/jedrek/keyboard_keys_swapper.sh'
remove here sleep and move it to script... as workaround

Comment: Very helpful :)

Comment: `sleep` is invalid syntax: need to specify a time. Try a longer time if 3 seconds also does not work.

Comment: The `xmodmap` commands in your script don’t run on wayland which might be the case on Ubuntu 21.10 … please check whether your system is using wayland or X

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 runs on X11. As I said `xmodmap` command works when I execute the script manually.